# how to give dark background to white icon so icon stands out against a light image?

Tags: android, icons, android-imageview, android-image, contrast

How can I add a dark, transparent background to a white icon so that the icon can be clearly seen when it's superimposed on a photo of any colour?

I got the icon from the Material design icons [here](https://material.io/icons/) so it comes in a variety of sizes. I'd rather not have to edit the icons if possible.

Here's a nice example from the built-in camera app of 2 icons standing out against a light background image. In my case the background doesn't have to be a circle. A squircle is fine too but preferably not a square. The background shape doesn't have to have a border like the ones below.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#40000000"/>
            
            <!--corners allow us to make the rounded corners -->
            <corners android:radius="15dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    </selector>
```

Add this XML file to your drawable. 8 digit color code `#40000000` is `AARRGGBB`, the first two-digit(for alpha) controls opacity, you can change 40 to as per your need. So you to set this drawable file as `background` of image and set icon in `src` property.

Comment: Better answer than mine. Little correction,  you dont need selector, just have shape in your xml file.

Comment: Yes, you're right - I did have just `shape` originally but I prefer to use `selector` as well because that allows me to tweak the background of the icon depending on what state the button's in. To be fair to you I didn't say the icon was in a button:).

Answer (score 2):

In this case layer-list is perfect, you don't have to edit your icon or to add any transparent images. Create your_icon_with_transparent_bg.xml in **drawable** with two layers (background and your icon):

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="30dp" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#00000000" />
            <solid android:color="#10000000" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:bottom="5px"
        android:left="5px"
        android:right="5px"
        android:top="5px">
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:src="@drawable/your_icon" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

And use in xml as **drawable** in ImageView or wherever you like, the result on white background is:

[image]

Here you can set borders (stroke), background color, set it to be squircle  or circle or circle -as it is on my image etc... customize as much as you like

Answer (score 0):

I've accepted the answer from @SurajVaishnav because it's simple and offers the useful [`selector`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList) option which means the state of the icon's background can change when it's pressed, or not pressed, for example. Here's what I went with in the end...

Create this **res/drawable/circle_white.xml** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="false">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <stroke
                android:width="0.5dp"
                android:color="@android:color/white" />

            <solid android:color="#88000000" />

            <padding
                android:bottom="8dp"
                android:left="8dp"
                android:right="8dp"
                android:top="8dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <stroke
                android:width="0.5dp"
                android:color="@android:color/white" />

            <solid android:color="#88FFFFFF" />

            <padding
                android:bottom="8dp"
                android:left="8dp"
                android:right="8dp"
                android:top="8dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Then wherever I need the button icon in a layout file I just do this:

```
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/icon_delete_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_white"
        android:contentDescription="@string/icon_delete_image_description"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_delete_white_24dp" />
```

`ic_delete_white_24dp` happens to be the icon I'm using. My delete icon then looks very similar to the one in the screenshot I posted in my question when it's not pressed; and its background changes to a grey shade when it's pressed.